# Determining first client to press a button

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a console game, where user connects via telnet to a server and has to press spacebar when sees a particular number.
I have one thread for each client connection.
I'm asking the best practice solution for the determining which client is the first to press spacebar.
Currently i"m making it this way:

```
public class Player {

    public Socket socket;
    public PrintWriter output;
    public BufferedReader input;
    public Player opponent;
    public boolean isPlaying;
```

it is all that player knows.

In the `run` method of the client thread i have:

```
    while (player.isPlaying == true && player.opponent.isPlaying == true)
        {
            player.isPlaying = listenAnswers();
        }               

        player.socket.close();
        player.opponent.socket.close();
```

And I have this in the `listenAnswers` method:

```
    int answer = view.receiveAnswer(player);
    if (answer == model.getWinningAction() )
    {
        view.sendWinMessage(player, isWinConditionMet);
        view.sendLoseMessage(player.opponent, isWinConditionMet);
        player.opponent.isPlaying = false;
        return false;
    }
```

`receiveAnswer` method basicly just returns `player.input.read();`

When I run my server, connect clients to it and one of them presses spacebar everything looks okey, but i become exeption in the second client thread while doing `read` in `receiveAnswer` method. Of course I can just ignore it, but I think there should be better solutions and I'm asking for them.
Basicly I do all the job in the winning thread, but is there a possibility when each client does something only for himself? the winner writes win message and the loser writes lose message.

Comment: Anytime you are accessing information in one thread from another thread, there has to be memory synchronization.  In this case you need to make `isPlaying` be at least `volatile`.  You might want to use `AtomicBoolean` if there is test/set operations.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a boolean that all threads can see and when you get a spacebar from one of the clients you check its value. If it is true, it means that the current thread lost. If it is false, you set it to true and this thread won.

Please note that you will have to syncrhonize access to that boolean since you will have an obvious race condition.

Anyway, that would be giving you the first thread that caught the spacebar.

If you want to make this even better, the client should send some timestamp, so you can check which one was pressed first (but you should then add some sort of integrity check to make sure that the clients aren't changing the actual timestamp, or sending fake timestamps).

Comment: I have tried to use `player.isPlaying` variable for this purpose, but the problem was: each client thread first checks this boolean and then waits for client input. First time when we check it's `true` and we are waiting till `false`, but we cannot check it another time untill we read something from the inputStream, so both clients have to type something before they know the result

Comment: But it's not the same to be playing than to have won. You want to read the input, and once you find a spacebar you check if any client has won. If noone has, then this thread won, otherwise it lost

Comment: You see, your way I can determine who's won only after each client presses a spacebar, but my target is to find it when the first client has PRESSED a spacebar and the second HASN'T PRESSED it yet

Comment: That's no problem...I'm assuming that io operations for each client happen in different threads. So whenever the first client presses a spacebar, the winnerFound boolean will be false, then you know that this client won, just because nobody has set it before. You don't need every client to press the spacebar

Comment: But each thread waits for the input, so when I type spacebar in one thread, okey, we know he's the winner, but the second thread will still wait for his own input. and just after typing spacebar he finds out that he lost. If I'm wrong I'd appreciate if you send some sample code

Comment: Oh, you want to wake up the other threads. Then you have to call Thread.interrupt() on the other threads and catch the InterruptedException. Alternatively, you can use non blocking input output (Java nio), which will also let you do all this in one thread

Comment: Okey, thanks, I'll make a deeper look at the `Thread.interrupt`method. I think it's what I was looking for. Thanks one more time. please, add this idea to your answer and I'll mark it as a solution